# What is the difference between ` and ' in react, one works and the other doesn't

Tags: reactjs

```
    backgroundImage: 'url(${background})'
```

VS

```
    backgroundImage: `url(${background})`
```

For some reason the second one with the ` gave me the result that I needed, but the first one with normal apostrophe ' did not. It took me forever to figure it out is there any way I can change my settings or is it supposed to me like that?

Comment: Search for JavaScript string interpolation. Yes, it's supposed to be like that.

Comment: [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 1):

> It is not something specific to react. It is a JS syntax.

The single quotes(') are using to define the strings.
The backticks(`) are using for concatenation.

i.e.: `` `url(${background}` `` is equivalent to 'url(' + background + ')'
The **background** should be a variable.

For further reference check [this](https://medium.com/better-programming/javascript-how-backticks-work-de269e0fb8ba)

Comment: Thank you @Akhil I put those quotes by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

When you include something in ' ', it treats it as string only.

If you are using template literals like `` `url${background}` ``. It checks for the variable background (which in your case might be undefined).